# Move multiple files into multiple directories with condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have multiple files whose first column contain has identifier "COM1-11","COM1-12","COM1-13","COM1-14","COM1-15"and "COM1-16" - the file name do not have identifier -

The first column of a file is like this:

> "Device name: ABC-DE(COM1-11)  Device type:ABC...Date:2020-07-14 10:46:59  "

Then, I want to take "COM1-11" part as identifier and move the file into corresponding folder "11","12","13","14","15" and "16" folder.

What I have reached so far:

```
import codecs
import pandas as pd
import shutil
import os

Raw_data_folder = r'C:\Users\Downloads\move_file_test'
files=os.listdir(Raw_data_folder)

Folder_11=r"C:\Users\Downloads\wished_dest\11"
Folder_12=r"C:\Users\Downloads\wished_dest\12"
Folder_13=r"C:\Users\Downloads\wished_dest\13"
Folder_14=r"C:\Users\Downloads\wished_dest\14"
Folder_15=r"C:\Users\Downloads\wished_dest\15"
Folder_16=r"C:\Users\Downloads\wished_dest\16"
```

then,

```
for f in files:
    doc=codecs.open(os.path.join(Raw_data_folder,f),'rU','UTF-16')
    identifier_1 = pd.read_csv(doc, sep='\t',nrows=0)
    identifier_2 = identifier_1 .columns.str[21:28]
    Folder_identifier=identifier_2 [0]
    
    if Folder_identifier=="COM1-11":
        shutil.move(os.path.join(Raw_data_folder,f),Folder_11)
    elif Folder_identifier=="COM1-12":
        shutil.move(os.path.join(Raw_data_folder,f),Folder_12)
    elif Folder_identifier=="COM1-13":
        shutil.move(os.path.join(Raw_data_folder,f),Folder_13)
    elif Folder_identifier=="COM1-14":
        shutil.move(os.path.join(Raw_data_folder,f),Folder_14)
    elif Folder_identifier=="COM1-15":
        shutil.move(os.path.join(Raw_data_folder,f),Folder_15)
    else: 
        shutil.move(os.path.join(Raw_data_folder,f),Folder_16)
```

When I run it, it only moves only the first file into the corresponding folder - the first file has "COM-11" and it gets moved to "11" folder.
Then, leave the following error message:

```
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file
because it is being used by another process:
'C:\\Users\\Downloads\\move_file_test\\Data_20200714_104659741.csv'
```

There must be missing for loop for the whole files, but I haven't get through yet.

Comment: Are the files open in another application (e.g. Excel)?

Comment: No, I closed all the csv files. The weird thing is that the very file mentioned in the error message - 'Data_20200714_104659741.csv' is already moved. But, it does not go to the next file to move.

Comment: In that case, maybe try closing the file before the if-else statements in the for loop: `doc.close()`.

Comment: Hello, zmike. it works perfect!! I appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try closing the file before the if-else statements in the for loop: `doc.close()`.

```
for f in files:
    doc=codecs.open(os.path.join(Raw_data_folder,f),'rU','UTF-16')
    identifier_1 = pd.read_csv(doc, sep='\t',nrows=0)
    identifier_2 = identifier_1 .columns.str[21:28]
    Folder_identifier=identifier_2 [0]
    
    # Close the file
    doc.close()

    if Folder_identifier=="COM1-11":
        shutil.move(os.path.join(Raw_data_folder,f),Folder_11)
    # ...
```